# blank row after data move to each column wise

Tags: vba, excel, formula

Please refer my image, So you may get id MY Data source  field
ea about my question,
 column A field have 20k values rows, I want to Create blank row after data move  to column-wise,( blank rows count=column wise count)

please give me solution vb MY Data source field
VBA or any formula       [MY DATA SOURCE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccINu.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Sub Test()
Dim myAreas     As Areas
Dim i           As Long
Dim c           As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set myAreas = Columns(1).SpecialCells(2, 1).Areas
    c = 1

    For i = 1 To myAreas.Count
        c = c + 1
        Cells(myAreas(i)(1).Row, c).Resize(myAreas(i).Count).Value = myAreas(i).Value
    Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: dear yasser khalil , thanks valid support
can you please check  this one also, I am looking output  right to left side, can you please check below my question link 
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20436712